# Alignment of objects in Android

Tags: android, alignment

In any layout i am not able to align the objects like textview, edittext ot button as per my wish.

I m New to android, please somebody help me, I wanted to design form like in .net windows programing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: where's the question? my answer is read the layout tutorials...

Comment: show us what you've tried so we can tell you where is your mistake and help you

Answer (score 3):

You can do it.Take RelativeLayout and take all your widgets inside it and use options like android:layout_centerInParent,android:layout_alignParentLeft,.....there are many more.

From [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) you can find about this layout.